# React Dynamic Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm new to React and I'm trying to create a modal that will be used to display different content. I have currently set this up to have different 'mode' states and each mode will display different markup, which gets passed into the Modal component as `this.props.children`

It seems to work to an certain extent but I'm having problems with state handling. The input works fine updating and displaying the current state of the input, but once this content is nested within the Modal component it does some strange things like no longer allowing you to type or show any key input at all, if there is state content, any keypresses are only updating the state with the last character.

I'm guessing this is because the Modal is a stateful component with a new construtor, the reference to 'this' and the `'handleChange'` function within the parent app is lost.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong or how to properly go about this?

Cheers guys :)

The code is here:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Modal extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.show !== this.props.show;
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log("[Modal] WillUpdate");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          transform: this.props.show ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(-100vh)",
          opacity: this.props.show ? "1" : "0",
          padding: "20px",
          border: "1px solid"
        }}
      >    
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      newItem: "",
      modalOpen: false,
      modalMode: ""
    };
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
  openModal(mode) {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true,
      modalMode: mode
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    let modalContent;

    switch (this.state.modalMode) {
      case 'addItem':
        modalContent = (
          <form>
            <h1>Add Item</h1>
            <input
          type="text"
          name="newItem"
          value={this.state.newItem}
          placeholder="Enter an item"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
          </form>
        )
        break;
      case 'editItem':
        modalContent = (
          <div>
          </div>
        )
        break;
      default:
        modalContent = (null)
    }



    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.openModal('addItem')}>Open Modal</button>
        <Modal show={this.state.modalOpen}>
          {modalContent}
        </Modal>
        <h2>Same inputs outside modal</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="newItem"
          value={this.state.newItem}
          placeholder="Enter an item"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="newItem"
          value={this.state.newItem}
          placeholder="Enter an item"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And a code sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/qzx14rmy6

Comment: Are you trying to get the modal input passed to App state?

Comment: Yes, ideally. I'd like to keep the state managed in the parent (App). Is this possible?

Comment: Are you tied to a specific version of react?, have you tried https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I'm using the latest version of React. No, not tried context before - had a look at the docs and it looks like I'll need to get my head around it.I've removed the 'shouldComponentUpdate' function from the Modal component which seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy and fast fix could be remove the "value" sync and the state will update just fine.

```js
<input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="Enter an item" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

I pointed out the real problem. In "shouldComponentUpdate", if you return "false" for any reason, component in NOT update with state. This method should be used carefully as it can break your app. Remove the method or return true and component will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work fine and it's something I've tried before, problem is I'll need to have the state as an input value in one of the Modal scenarios. For example, an edit item Modal if that make sense?

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: That seems to work :) The Modal code was copy pasted so was unsure what the 'shouldComponentUpdate' life cycle function did, so left it.

Thanks.